# AsyncTask not even starting

Tags: android, android-asynctask, navigation-drawer, progressdialog

I was sitting 5 hours on one code with `AyncTask` which was not running properly. I just created another simple `Activity` (because in last one `onPostExecute()` wasn't working) and now this simple `Activity` is also not starting the `AsyncTask`. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class ServerStatus extends Activity {
Context context;    
private ProgressDialog pd;  
int a;  
TextView test;  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.server_status);
        context=this;
        test=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcomemessage);
        new Download().execute();


    }

    public class Download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        protected Void onPreExecute(Void... arg0) {
            pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pd.setTitle("Processing...");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait.");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.show();
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            a++;
            return null;
        }


        protected Void onPostExecute(Void... arg0) {
            if (pd!=null) 
                pd.dismiss();
            test.setText(a);
            return null;
        }

    } 

}
```

Also, does `NavigationDrawer` block UI thread? Because I can't even update `TextView` when I implement it.

Comment: You should be doing UI component modifications from within the onProgressUpdate(). Navigation drawers do not block the UI thread. What occurs when you try and run it?

Comment: Here's my [answer to a similar question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752210/cant-see-progressdialog-while-asynctask-run-in-background/25752553#25752553

Comment: Well, i was updating UI Thread from onPostExecute() so maybe there was my problem (it was not updating anything or even doing anything like it wasn't called). Gonna give it a try tommorow then. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: You should really use the @Override annotation. Your compiler would tell you the issue right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods aren't correct. You should add the `@Override` annotation to them so it will yell at you when doing it wrong.

`onPreExecute()` doesn't take any `params` so it should be

```
@Override
protected Void onPreExecute() {
```

also change the param type of `onPostExecute() to

```
@Override
 protected Void onPostExecute(Void arg0) {
```

Remove the "..." [See Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) for an explanation.

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

[Post explaining AsyncTask and getting values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898039/using-asynctask/18898105#18898105)

those params in the class declaration are for `doInBackground()`, `onProgressUpdate()`, and `onPostExecute()`

As far as the `NavDrawer`, I'm not sure what issue you are having with that.

Comment: Seems to be working but probably i did something wrong because after adding @Override to onPostExecute() it says "The method onPostExecute(Void...) of type ServerStatus.download must override or implement a supertype method". Probably i messed something with arguments but i would be grateful if you or another person would correct me. After 5 hrs im not thinking straight...

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your code in onPreExecute

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
```

to

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

Comment: The method getActivity() is undefined for the type ServerStatus.download

Comment: Sorry I thought you were working with Fragments, my bad